# c# from json string to object

Tags: c#, json

How can i create object from this json string.

Its this function https://wiki.gtanet.work/index.php?title=fromJson

```
    [["Test item 2",2,1337,1,2,"Użyj test2"],["Test item 1",2,1337,1,1,"Użyj test1"]]
```

I tried this

```
   items f = API.shared.fromJson(myString).ToObject<items>();
```

And class

```
public class items
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int weight {get;set;}
    public int model {get;set;}
    public int scala {get;set;}
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string rightClick {get;set;}
}
```

error:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid property identifier character: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use json which is you shared. There is a way to parse this json;

```
var jsonStr = "[[\"Test item 2\",2,1337,1,2,\"Użyj test2\"],[\"Test item 1\",2,1337,1,1,\"Użyj test1\"]]";
            dynamic parsedObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
            parsedObjectList = (IEnumerable)parsedObjectList;
            List<items> itemsList = new List<items>();
            foreach (var itemList in parsedObjectList)
            {
                var item = new items();
                item.name = itemList[0];
                item.weight = itemList[1];
                item.model = itemList[2];
                item.scala = itemList[3];
                item.id = itemList[4];
                item.rightClick = itemList[5];
                itemsList.Add(item);
            }
```

Comment: Using the generic type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerableT>' requires `1' type argument(s)

Comment: did you add using System.Collections and 
using System.Collections.Generic ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your json string is slightly incorrect. it should be declared as a 'key/value' pair: 
`{[["name":"Test item 2","weight":2, "model":1337, "scala":1,"id":2,"rightClick":"Użyj test2"]........]}`

http://json.org/example.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your JSON is an array of array and you try to convert it to a List of object. Can you change your JSON like this:

```
[{"name": "Test item 2", "weight": 2, "model": 1337, "scala": 1, "id": 2, "rightClick": "Użyj test2"}, {...}]
```